# Ubuntu 18.04 and Tracker : files properly indexed, but not searchable in GS/Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, locate, tracker

On a clean 18.04 install, I added tracker to index my data. My data lies on a second harddisk and is symlinked to my homedir on the first one using the standard ~/Documents ~/Music etc. paths.

After taking quite a lot of time to figure out why indexing would never end and eat 100% of the CPU for days (it was due to some amiga "playsid" chiptunes : I should report this bug to GNOME), I managed to get my indexing done.

tracker status indicates indexing is over (over 100 000 files)
tracker "search" *does return* the relevant results. Only strange thing is the first line "store" "0%" "idle" while the 3 next entries indicate indexing is complete.

Indexing did succeed. For instance, if I create a "test.txt" file in my homedir only containing the word "carabistouille", it does appear when searching for "carabistouille" in the terminal.

HOWEVER, the gnome shell & Nautilus searches never yield any result. They seem to only return the results returned by "mlocate" (which happened before installing tracker), based on the filename, not on the content (and they didn't index my symlinked directories on the 2nd partition).

Any idea ? Could it be related to the fact Canonical used a former version of Nautilus (3.26) while the rest of the stack is 3.28 ? Is it a bug ? Am I missing something ? I'm quite confident it'll be fixed in 18.10 as Canonical plans to enable tracker in the next release.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Cheers !

Comment: I also tried to get this to work on Ubuntu, but also on Antergos linux (Arch based distro). It just did not work on either of these distributions. Looks like this is plain broken, and I am surprised not to hear more on this.

Comment: Hmm, maybe we should try under Fedora. I could clearly use it under the previous Ubuntu and GS versions. It is really supposed to work and I clearly read somewhere from a Nautilus dev it was disabled under Ubuntu...

Comment: afaiu its resolved now? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1767817 ; at least there is a way to contribute to its solution (by testing and digging deeper into the info given in that thread).